# In html. How can i add two rows in a column when i have multiple columns in a table?

Tags: html

Basically I have:

```
<tr>
<td>first</td>
<td>second</td>
<td>third</td>
</tr>
```

How can I add rows thirdA thirdB inside column third?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl6FK.png

Comment: Either add a new table or play with rowspan or colspan

Comment: Is this something that putting a <ul> inside of your <td> can solve? Can you provide a visual of what you expect?

Comment: I have added a link

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstand your question. Do you mean something like this?

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>first</td>
<td>second</td>
<td><table><tr>
<td>ThirdA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ThirdB</td>
</tr></table></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

or

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>first</td>
<td>second</td>
<td>ThirdA <br> ThirdB</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

or

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan=2>first</td>
<td rowspan=2>second</td>
<td>ThirdA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ThirdA</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

When adding new data you'll have to do this for example 3.

```css
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>first</td>
    <td rowspan=2>second</td>
    <td>ThirdA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ThirdB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan=2> STUFF FOR 1</td>
    <td rowspan=2> STUFF FOR 2</td>
    <td> STUFF FOR 3A</td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
    <td> STUFF FOR 3B</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes the answer is correct. I couldnt find online that i can add a table inside a table

Comment: On your third example, using colspan and rowspan, could i avoid jumping in a newline ? Because it jumps a new line if i try to add a new td at the end of last /tr

Comment: @MarianTele see edits